# CalDavZAP cross-domain setup

Tags: calendar, cross-domain, caldav

I need to install CalDavZAP cross-domain, but i have no access to CalDav server. I get error message in Firebug:

Error: [netCheckAndCreateConfiguration: 'PROPFIND https://caldav.servername.com/dav/principals/'] code: '0' status: 'error' - see https://www.inf-it.com/caldavzap/readme.txt (cross-domain setup).

Can I configure CalDavZAP or should I use another client?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to (re)configure CalDavZAP, you need to (re)configure your CalDAV server to return proper CORS headers (see the readme.txt). This is JavaScript limitation, and because CalDavZAP is JavaScript application there is no way to get over that restriction directly in CalDavZAP.

The same limitation applies to all JavaScript applications!

Comment: Thanks, i have already disabled the same origin policy on Google Chrome.